# Material Design Component scrolling tab not scrolling

Tags: vue.js, material-design, material-components, material-components-web, mdc-components

I am using mdc-tab-scroller in my vue.js application. I want to have the scroll behaviour as in [here](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/tabs) under the section of "scrolling tabs". Have tried different approaches but don't know how to get it working. This is my very first experience with vue.js and material design components so don't really know if I am on right path of implementation.

```
    <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
        <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
            <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">
                <mdc-tab-bar>
                    <mdc-tab :to="{ path: getTab1() }" >Tab1</mdc-tab>
                    <mdc-tab :to="{ path: getTab2() }" >Tab2</mdc-tab>
                    <mdc-tab :to="{ path: getTab3() }" >Tab3</mdc-tab>
                    <mdc-tab :to="{ path: getTab4() }" >Tab4</mdc-tab>
                    <mdc-tab :to="{ path: getTab5() }" >Tab5</mdc-tab>
                    <mdc-tab :to="{ path: getTab6() }" >Tab6</mdc-tab>
                </mdc-tab-bar> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you mean by scroll behavior the smooth animation of border-bottom?

Comment: No. I want "scrolling tabs" behaviour as in the link I have shared in my post (i-e https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/tabs). Upon clicking a specific tab item, It is to bring in focus the tab that is not fully visible either on right side (when moving right) or left side (when moving left).

Comment: when you implement the same code you don't have that behavior?

Comment: NO. I am not getting that.

Comment: didn't you miss to import  any module?

Comment: I can see "@material/tab-scroller": "^0.39.0" under dependencies section of Package.json file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179633/discussion-between-learning-curve-and-boussadjra-brahim).